# How to use controller in other file js with route-ui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I got an example from here : http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router  and I see an example about using route-ui as below:

```
$stateProvider

    // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
    })

    // nested list with custom controller
    .state('home.list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
        }
    })

    // nested list with just some random string data
    .state('home.paragraph', {
        url: '/paragraph',
        template: 'I could sure use a drink right now.'
    })
```

my question is : how can I use controller in other file and then call the name of that controller into .state's option ?

Here is my controller that I want to use in other file :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("myCtrl", [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.dogs = ['name 1', 'name 2', 'name 3', 'name 4']; 
    })
})();
```

and here is my rout-ui :

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home/partial-home.html',
            controller: 'myCtrl'
        })

        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'about/partial-about.html'
        });

});
```

and below is my html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>testRoute</title>

    <!-- testRoute references -->
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="routerApp">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.11/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="scripts/myController.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just doing controller: 'Name_of_your_Controller'?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to use the name of that controller, but I got an error message : Bad Argument

Comment: This is my controller:

(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("myCtrl", [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.dogs = ['name 1', 'name 2', 'name 3', 'name 4']; 
    })
})();

and here that I use the name of controller:

var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home/partial-home.html',
            controller: 'myCtrl'
        })
});

Comment: That sounds good, can you post the code where you try to set up the controller in the route? Also, are you sure you included your controller file in the HTML file?

Comment: Now I've to posted my example

Comment: @SaXi : Did you solve your problem??? Actually, i also want do like this.. If already soved, can you share the solutions..